# Run part of program inside Fortran code for a limited time

Tags: fortran

I wanted to run a code (or an external executable) for a specified amount of time. For example, in Fortran I can

```
 call system('./run')
```

Is there a way I can restrict its run to let's say 10 seconds, for example as follows

```
 call system('./run', 10)
```

I want to do it from inside the Fortran code, example above is for system command, but I want to do it also for some other subroutines of my code. for example,

```
 call performComputation(10)
```

where performComputation will be able to run only for 10 seconds. The system it will run on is Linux.

thanks!

Comment: What language are you calling from?

Comment: And what platform are you on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDITED**

Ah, I see - you want to call *a part of the current program* a limited time. I see a number of options for that...

**Option 1**

Modify the subroutines you want to run for a limited time so they take an additional parameter, which is the number of seconds they may run. Then modify the subroutine to get the system time at the start, and then in their processing loop get the time again and break out of the loop and return to the caller if the time difference exceeds the maximum allowed number of seconds.

On the downside, this requires you to change every subroutine. It will exit the subroutine cleanly though.

**Option 2**

Take advantage of a threading library - e.g. pthreads. When you want to call a subroutine with a timeout, create a new thread that runs alongside your main program in parallel and execute the subroutine inside that thread of execution. Then in your main program, sleep for 10 seconds and then kill the thread that is running your subroutine.

This is quite easy and doesn't require changes to all your subroutines. It is not that elegant in that it chops the legs off your subroutine at some random point, maybe when it is least expecting it.

Imagine time running down the page in the following example, and the main program actions are on the left and the subroutine actions are on the right.

```
MAIN                                SUBROUTINE YOUR_SUB
... something ..
... something ...
f_pthread_create(,,,YOUR_SUB,)      start processing
sleep(10)                           ... calculate ...
                                    ... calculate ...
                                    ... calculate ...
f_pthread_kill()
... something ..
... something ...
```

**Option 3**

Abstract out the subroutines you want to call and place them into their own separate executables, then proceed as per my original answer below.

Whichever option you choose, you are going to have to think about how you get the results from the subroutine you are calling - will it store them in a file? Does the main program need to access them? Are they in global variables? The reason is that if you are going to follow options 2 or 3, there will not be a return value from the subroutine.

**Original Answer**

If you don't have `timeout`, you can do

```
call system('./run & sleep 10; kill $!')
```

Comment: I have updated the answer in the light of further information in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way. take a look at the linux command `timeout`

```
# run command for 10 seconds and then send it SIGTERM kill message
# if not finished.
call system('timeout 10 ./run')
```

Example

```
# finishes in 10 seconds with a return code of 0 to indicate success.
sleep 10 

# finishes in 1 second with a return code of `124` to indicate timed out.
timeout 1 sleep 10
```

You can also choose the type of kill signal you want to send by specifying the `-s` parameter. See `man timeout` for more info.